# Upgrading wget on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: apt, ubuntu-16.04, wget

I'm trying to upgrade my copy of `wget` on the server. Currently its running:

> 1.17.1-1ubuntu1.4

The problem is that I need **1.19** so I can get a new feature:

http://tomszilagyi.github.io/2017/02/Wget-retry-on-http-error

> My patch has been part of the changes released as Wget version 1.19.1,
>   so now (if you run that version or newer) you can just write something
>   like:
>
> wget --retry-on-http-error=503 ...

We are having issues with a website giving 502 errors back when trying to request the images from them. Their tech guys are looking into it, but for the mean time I need a way to auto-retry the 502 files. This seems to fit the bill, but I can't seem to get it to upgrade.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install wget
```

...gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version (1.17.1-1ubuntu1.4).
```

I'm not sure what else to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to go via the package manager, as long as you know which version goes where.

The GNU wget source tarball + compilation instructions can be found here: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/faq.html#download

If this is your first time compiling software, try it on a separate computer or VM first - preferably one with the same OS version - so you know what to expect.